# Alter/Change specific URL

Tags: php

Let's say I have sample URL as below:

```
blahlah.com/index.php?page=1&subpage=1&result=ok
```

How to alter only value `subpage` into `2` (or something else) with php code. It would be like below:

```
blahlah.com/index.php?page=1&subpage=2&result=ok
```

**Note:** Only `subpage` value that will change.

Any suggestion or help is very appreciated.

Comment: Please post some code of exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
// Your host
$domain = "blahlah.com/index.php?";

// Your GET parameters
$params = [
 'page' => 1,
  'subpage' => 1,
  'result' => 'ok'
];

// Print default parameters
echo $domain.http_build_query($params)."\n";

// Change 'subpage' parameter value 
$params['subpage'] = 2;

// Print the updated parameters
echo $domain.http_build_query($params);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
blahlah.com/index.php?page=1&subpage=1&result=ok
blahlah.com/index.php?page=1&subpage=2&result=ok
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Y4jUr

Comment: @Ardi: Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on tick mark so that the question is considered resolved. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$url = 'blahlah.com/index.php?page=1&subpage=1&result=ok';

// We get query row from our url
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// Explode query row to array (now it's like ['page' => '1', 'subpage' => '1',... ])
parse_str($query, $explodedQuery);

// Change your data
$explodedQuery['subpage'] = 2;

// Create new query and url
$url = 'blahlah.com/index.php?' . http_build_query($explodedQuery);
```